# Generating random numbers with equal sizes

Tags: java, random

I know how to generate random numbers,but
Is it possible to generate random float numbers with equal sizes in java?
e.g.   generating 0.4 number 100 times (like this 0.4, 0.4, 0.4,........)
thanks for help

Comment: What is the 'size' of a number?

Comment: What do you mean by the "size" of a number?  Is it the number of bits, digits?  what does `0.4` mean?  Is it the average, or the maximum, or the range?

Comment: `random numbers with different sizes` you might be the only one who understands this. ;)

Comment: Use simple math.. If I wanted to get random numbers of size 3, I would do `100 + random.nextInt(899);`

Comment: i mean generating 0.4 or any other float numbers 100 times

Comment: Do you mean 100 times the same value (0.4, 0.4, 0.4, ...) or 100 times random values (0.4, 0.5, 0.3, ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> e.g. generating 0.4 number 100 times (like this 0.4, 0.4,
>   0.4,........)

```
private float getRandom() {
    return 0.4; // Guaranteed to be random
}

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    System.out.println(getRandom());
}
```